# Why did the Ewoks think C-3PO was a god?

Tags: star-wars, return-of-the-jedi, ewoks

Is there any evidence about the specific reason that they instantly came to revere him as a deity?

They must have seen droids before, especially if the Empire had been there long enough to build the Death Star to such an extent.

And R2-D2 was there too, so what was it about C-3PO that they chose him specifically? Did he resemble a figure they already worshiped? Or was it because he was an entirely unfamiliar species that could speak their language?

Comment: I think a golden shiny man would be revered in many stone-age cultures. I have no evidence to back this up though.

Comment: @Burgi, so would flying people that command lightning, yet there is no indication that the Ewoks worship imperial scout troopers. As Mike has pointed out, they must have known about aliens and droids and still saw C3PO as a chosen one.

Comment: @EikePierstorff - It's noteworthy that a protocol droid would be a vanishingly rare sight on Endor and that gold is a rare colour for a droid. Rare + rare = unlikely to have been seen before

Comment: It's a ~100-150 year old trope in Western literature and cinema that a technologically advanced western man, typically white, is received as a god or highly respected person by less technologically developed indigenous groups: http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/MightyWhitey

Comment: Droids were not particularly common amongst the Imperials. The only one I can remember seeing is the Roomba that Chewie scares whilst 'imprisoned' by Han aboard the Death Star

Comment: Because he was eternal, shiny and chrome.

Comment: Because Luke made him fly with Force Telekinesis. I don't think they were familiar with the Force.

Comment: @SS-3.1415926535897932384626433 But that happened _after_ the Ewoks had already determined he was a god; that just showed he was angry with them for attempting to roast his friends.

Comment: @iamnotmaynard OK. I have forgotten the sequence of events.

Comment: Has there been any mention of the Empire communicating with or even respecting Ewoks? You only worship those who can be benevolent to you (even if only by appeasing them), and if the Empire ignores the Ewoks like an elephant unintentionally crushes an ant colony, then they are not gods in the Ewoks' eyes. Combine that with C3PO being the only one capable of speaking their language, and he instantly becomes the most important foreigner they have ever seen.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

There's a brief mention in the film's official novelisation that C-3PO's coming was foretold by prophets as part of the Ewok's oral tradition.

> This golden god, whose return to us has been prophesied since the First Tree, tells us now he will not be our Master, tells us we are free to choose as we will—that we must choose; as all living things must choose their own destiny.

Since the Ewok language is part of C-3PO's language file as an "old dialect", it stands to reason that they've been contacted before the arrival of the Imperial troops. It's possible that their culture was influenced at this point.

Comment: A Star Wars question is posted, and immediately Richard is there with a quote from a novelization which answers the question pretty much definitively. Just another day :)

Comment: @WolfieInu - It's only half an answer though. The follow-up questions are "When were the Ewoks first contacted? & Did their Ewoks belief in a golden god predate their first contact?"

Comment: Just to throw a minor stock-scfi-fi-hammer in any future conjecture; are the Ewoks indigenous to the forest moon of Endor or were they brought there by an advanced civilisation and then abandoned there?

Comment: @GeoffAtkins - According to Lucasfilm's '[Star Wars and History](http://www.theforce.net/latestnews/story/SW_And_History_Available_For_PreOrder_146830.asp)', the Ewoks are **indigenous** to the forest moon. Obviously that's not a canon source of info, but it is studio-authorised and written "in close collaboration with George Lucas and Lucasfilm"

Comment: Reminds me of the Bene Gesserit's *Missionaria Protectiva* from Dune, where the Bene Gesserit planted superstitions and prophecies so the target cultures could later be exploited.

Comment: As of the Star Wars Character Encyclopedia from 2011, C-3PO could talk to them because he knew Yuzzum, a language spoken by another sentient species from Endor that had found its way to other planets (for example, there are a couple Yuzzum in Jabba's Palace).

Comment: @MiloPrice - I'm pretty sure that that book was never part of the official Star Wars canon. That being said, it's quite an interesting factoid.

Answer (score 2):

If I was an Ewok confronted with a C3-PO I would assume that »it« is something supernatural due to its shiny and otherwordly (from Ewok perspective) appearance. It appears to be a kind of being, as it moves and interacts on a level that I can react to, but it is obviously out of my world, so it must be a higher power (a God), and I better treat it like one, lest it is hostile. (At least this is my assumptive interpretation of Ewok psychology.)

Comment: If there were no other "otherwordly" creatures that the Ewok had seen this might offer some value as an answer.

Answer (score -1):

The ewoks are an ancient civilization right ? .. So they live with NATURE, they live in the forest. On the contrast Nature/Technology (being the other pole of evolution) C3PO was a BEING MADE BY TECHNOLOGY with life of it's own. Looking into the future like million years forward, the ewoks knew that C3PO (or any robotic living talking thing) would be a God. Their God.

Comment: For that, they would have to know he's a _robot_. How would they know he's a robot if they don't have technology?

Answer (score -2):

The Ewoks were previously visited by a gold protocol droid. At least 1000 years previous. It was a beneficial encounter. Perhaps this is where they acquired knowledge to build gliders, but this was not the main benefit associated with the event. Probably the protocol droid had aided in repelling an invader in some minor way. A droid does not eat, breath, deficate or use genitals. God-like properties yet no god-like powers except the gift of tongues. Merely associating the coming of the 'gold deity' with the victory is sufficient and likley. Later, there was a legitimate prophecy given by a force sensitive ewok that another gold deity would come and help repel invaders (the prophecy, *or the prophet*, left out the presence of human companions). Ewoks knew but did not nessissarily count on the prophecy. They would not and did not expect the gold deity to have companions or powers other than tongues. When the prophecy proved true (gold deity with tongues when an invader is near), there where no sceptics. When the gold deity claimed powers, this was inconsistant with their knowledge of the gold deity, thus, they were skeptical and 'fear-of-god' shocked when the gold deity demonstraited flight without wings or a machine. So what if flight was 'otherwise normal' to ewoks; "What other powers has he be hiding?" was certainly in their minds. "Can he shoot beams, call fire from the sky, command earthquakes?" Ewoks knew stormtroopers could do all that, but they didn't expect it from the gold deity.

Comment: Who was the other gold protocol droid? Can you provide a source for your claims?